# How to insert the values to the database by using select result

Tags: mysql

I want to put the value to the database
and the value is result of the selection

this is the selection query:

```
SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(NOW(),user_birthday)/365 )as age from user_info
```

how can i insert the age value to the other table every day by using scheduled event

Answer (score 1):

`Mysql` support the `insert...select` statement.

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
  [INTO] tbl_name
  [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
  [(col_name,...)]
SELECT ...
  [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col_name=expr
    [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

[documents of mysql select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: how can i put the query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Your `phpmyadmin` is a client to `mysql server`.  How to use `phpmyadmin` client is another question. You may read the [phpmyadmin docs](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO  table_name_to_which_data_has_to_be_copied (SELECT column_names FROM table_name WHERE condition);

Comment: CREATE 
 EVENT cal_age 
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS now() 
 DO BEGIN
 Insert into user_info(
 SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(NOW(),user_birthday)/365 )as age from user_info);
what wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you satisfy the syntax of events,Find below the syntax                                                                                                                                             
->Edit your query like,  
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT cal_age ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS NOW() ENDS '2015-08-25 14:45.10' DO BEGIN SELECT * FROM new.`course`; END$$
DELIMITER;;                                                                                              
->I hope that would work.